# What are the possible effects of outliers on a regression analysis

Tags: regression, linear-regression

What are the possible effects of outliers on a regression analysis?

I know that outliers can dramatically change the magnitude of the regression coefficients and even change the direction of the coefficient signs. I am wondering however if there are set effects (a list) which are effects of outliers?

Answer (score 1):

1. May have severe influence on fitted line ⇒ systematic lack of fit at other observations
2. May inflate residual variance

   ⇒ low R2

   ⇒  non-significant slope β1
3. Observations with large standardized residuals (numerically larger than 2) are flagged by Minitab